# Check node type in macros

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, crystal-lang

*From [#5028](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5028)*

How do I know a type class in macros? For example, this:

```
class A
  Const = 42

  macro is_int(val)
    {% p "#{val} is int: #{val.is_a?(Int32)}" %}
  end

  is_int(Const)
end
```

prints `false`.

Answer (score 2):

[@asterite](https://github.com/asterite) says:

> `is_a?` in macros check if a node is of a given [AST node](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Crystal/Macros/ASTNode.html) type.

Therefore, you should use `val.resolve.is_a?(NumberLiteral)` instead.

**Bonus:** if you want to check if node is descendant of a class, you can use `val.resolve < AncestorClass` (e.g. `val.resolve < ::Enum` to check if `val` is `Enum`).